# И снова про... "про"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Скажите, пожалуйста, предлога "про" в русском языке вообще нет? Только "о"? Или "про" все-таки можно употреблять?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему нет?  
В словаре ***Кузнецова***, например, статья об этом предлоге такая: 
ПРО
 1. ПРО, предлог. кого-что.
 2. О ком-, чём-л., относительно, насчёт кого-, чего-л. *Рассказывать про свой отпуск, про экскурсии, про новых друзей. Про меня забыли. Фильм про любовь. Про всё и про вся (разг.; обо всех и обо всём).*
 3. Разг. Для, ради, в предназначение для кого-, чего-л. *Эта вещь не про тебя. Не про нас*

Правда, в современном русском языке предлог ПРО чаще используется в разговорном стиле, а в книжных предпочтительнее предлоги О, ОБ, ОБО.

Answer (score 3):

*Синонимический ряд образуют предлоги с изъяснительным значением, например: разговоры о поездке – про поездку – насчет поездки – относительно поездки – касательно поездки. В этих сочетаниях можно отметить убывающую конкретизацию предмета речи и стилистическое различие: **разговорный характер предлогов про** и **насчет**, книжный характер (присущий старой и деловой речи) предлогов касательно и относительно и нейтральный предлог о при глаголах речи или мысли и соответствующих существительных*. - Розенталь. Литературное редактирование текстов.

Из учебника "Русский язык и культура речи" Голуб (30 лет назад нас учили так же): В современном русском литературном языке выделяются  функциональные стили:  научный, публицистический, официально-деловой, которые выступают преимущественно в  письменной форме речи, и  разговорный, которому свойственна главным образом устная форма речи.

Таким образом, предлог "про" вполне можно употреблять в разговорном стиле речи.

Comment: >разговорный характер предлогов про и насчет,   
Словари, однако, не фиксируют. Что все-таки заставляет думать, что здесь разговорный (стиль?) использовано не в том, счмыле, о котором говорит EkaterinaKas.

Answer (score 0):

Странная постановка вопроса. Есть, конечно, такой предлог.

Насчет стилей. 
В книжной речи - да там скорее будет о/об/обо но разговорный характер "про" я бы не приписывал.  Разговорный - это то, что немного вне литературной нормы, а "про" вполне нормативен. Видимо, имелась в виду устная речь. Это не то же, что и "разговорный стиль".

Comment: Разговорный стиль - это стиль литературного языка, нельзя сказать, что он вне нормы. Вне нормы - просторечие.

Comment: Нет, это смотря как к норме подходить.
Я (вслед за Аванесовым) предерживаюсь следующей линейки допустимости: норма-разговорное-просторечное-неправльное-грубо_неправильное. Других шкал не знаю. 

В любом случае "разговорный" и "книжный" здесь неуместно, поскольку ПРО нормально используется в устной речи, какого бы стиля она не была.

Comment: А я с детства слышала, что "про" — это по-украински, а "о" — по-русски

Comment: В каких-то случаях - да, такое соответвие есть. Но это никак не сказывается на самом факте существования предлога в русском.

Более, того, я продолжаю утверждать, что ни о какой разговорности тут речи быть не может. Это вполне литературная норма.

ЗЫ Жалко, что мои оппоненты отказались спорить по сути... А между тем весьма обязывающее отнесение "про" к разговорному стилю не фиксируется ни одним словарем... Полагаю, что причина все-таки в смешении понятий "разговорный стиль" и "устная речь".

Comment: Как это ни одним словарем? Посмотрите хотя бы Ожегова. Есть и в других словарях помета "разговорное". А у Розенталя прямое указание на это.

Comment: Есть помета "разговорное", но не во всех же значениях. См. выше ответ Екатерины: в 1-м и 2-м значениях нет никаких помет, значит, это не разговорное, а вполне литературное слово. НО: (во 2-м значении) "про все и про вся" - выражение уже разговорное. Так что нельзя однозначно сказать.

Comment: Да, разумеется, я про основное значение.  
А по сути...  
При небольшом усилии я могу представить не только в стилистически нейтрайной речи, но даже в научном стиле. 
Вот например: Имяреков в работе "О предлогах" говорит про три случая использования предлога про в нацной речи.
Хотя сказать, например, "сообщает про" у меня в подобном стиле язык не повернётся.

Comment: Согласна. Тут дело тонкое, надо контекст чувствовать и понимать, где смело можно употреблять "про", а где лучше этого не делать.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме книжного и разговорного стилей, есть еще нейтральный, как мне кажется (когда лексика стилистически нейтральная). То есть это нечто среднее, и оно тоже относится к норме. Что-то вроде золотой середины. И "про" вполне подпадает под лит. норму, только не во всех значениях (согласно определениям словаря). Так что я не согласна, что "про" характерно только для разговорной речи.

Comment: Стилей ещё много можно придумать.  
Ещё раз выскажу предположение, что речь идёт не остиле как таковом, а именно о разговорной речи. Или еще точнее - устной.

Comment: Давайте все-таки говорить "разговорная лексика" (которая уместна для разговорного стиля). А то "разговорная речь" - слишком широкое понятие, практически необъятное. В разговорной, а конкретнее в устной речи, может быть и сленг, и просторечие, и непосредственно разговорная лексика, и мат, да и вообще все что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что разница - едва уловимая - есть, и больше смысловая, чем стилистическая.

Я согласна с подслушанным на лингвофоруме:

"о" более конкретно, "про" абстрактнее.

"Песня про тебя — о чем-то внешнем, несущественном (винительный падеж);
песня о тебе — конкретно о тебе, о твоей душе, сущности, о чем-то твоем (предложный падеж) ".

Или:

"Рассказ о Гапоне. Гапон -- главное действующее лицо.
Рассказ про Гапона. Гапон -- одно из главных действующих лиц".

[Источник](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/183045173) )))